# How to specify OUTPUT for Java protobuf classes

Tags: java, cmake, protoc

I've been working to prevent our CMake system at work from always regenerating the Java wrapper classes for our protobufs; as it stands, a single change in a C++ unit test requires rebuilding a couple hundred of these.  The Python and C++ protoc commands are not executed in the same circumstances.

Since I don't use the Java class files, I was not paying too close attention; but I've finally figured out the issue: when compiling `XMessage.proto` which contains a protobuf called `XMessage`, protoc generates the output file as `XMessageOuterClass.java` (to match the name used for the wrapper class). This does not match the expected output name specified in CMake, and so it always rebuilds.

My question is: how can I tell, from a CMake level, whether the protobuf will or will not have this name mangling, so that I can specify the command's `OUTPUT` correctly and prevent unneeded rebuilding?

Comment: How do you generate java files with protobuf? The module [FindProtobuf](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindProtobuf.html), shipped with CMake, can only generate C++ and Python files.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I guess the answer is, we have a custom FindProtobuf. I didn't write it; I just want it to stop misbehaving.

Comment: So you need to specify in the CMake OUTPUT those files, which are **actually** produced by protobuf. (In other words, you specification of OUTPUT should **predict** files which will be created by protobuf compiler.)